# present new modal view controller then dismiss old modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

i want to dismiss my current view controller then load up a new view controller. this seems like it should work:

```
FieldReportViewController *fieldReport = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fieldReportView"];
[self presentModalViewController:fieldReport animated:YES];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

i present the new modal, then dimiss the old one. but the old one doesn't actually get dismissed.

any idea how i can get this done or why this won't work?

Comment: You have to dismiss modal views inside the class of the modal view itself.

Comment: @class the class wher the modal to dismiss is declared in

Answer (score 0):

You are not dismissing the old modal view controller....you are dismissing the new one you just presented.  Try dismissing the modal view controller first.

Answer (score 0):

first dismiss the old view before present the nezt one or use the actual names instead of "self"

add this code:

```
 #import "class of the to dismiss view.h"
 @class class of the to dismiss view
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present a modal view controller, depending on which iOS version you're using, you're setting the property `modalViewController` or `presentingViewController` of the 1st modal to a second modal and adding the 2nd view controller to the view hierarchy. If you were successful in removing the first modal, the second modal would no longer be attached to any view hierarchy.

What you may want to consider is using a single view controller and just replacing the view for that modal view. I think this would give you what you want.

Alternatively, you should probably dismiss the first modal and from the previous view controller present the second modal.